# Solving $(y'' + 2iy' + 1)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(y'' + 2iy' + 1)y = 0$$

I tried to solve this problem by substituting $y=e^{mx}$ to find the auxiliary equation and solve further. But I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Separate it and you can get $y''+2iy'+1=0\lor y=0$. Then make substitution $y'\to u$.

Comment: What was the difficulty that you encountered? What is the equation for $m$ that you obtained?

Comment: Are you sure that the equation is correct and that it was not $(D^2+2iD+1)y=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$, that is $$y''+2iy'+y=0?$$

Comment: Actually, the question was in the form of (D2+2iD+1)y=0

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is given by $$y(x)=0$$ then we Substitute $$y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$ for the homogeneous part. For a particular solution make the ansatz $$y_p=a_1x$$
For your Control: the solution is given by $$y(x)=C_1+\frac{ix}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear differential equation and can be solved as

$$
y = y_h+y_p\\
y''_h+2iy'_h=0\\
y''_p+2iy'_p=1
$$

The homogeneous solution is obtained by substituting $y_h = e^{\lambda x}$ giving

$$
\lambda^2+2i\lambda = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda\in \{0,-2i\}
$$

and then

$$
y_h = \frac{C_0}{2}e^{-2ix}+C_1
$$

and for $y_p$ we have

$$
y_p = \frac{i x}{2}
$$

and finally

$$
y =  \frac{i x}{2}+ \frac{C_0}{2}e^{-2ix}+C_1
$$

joined with $y = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$(y'' + 2iy' + 1)y = 0$$

you have $y=0$ as a solution and also
$$y'' + 2iy' + 1 = 0$$
Substitute $z=y'$
$$z+2iz=-1$$
Use $e^{2ix}$ as integrating factor
$$(ze^{2ix})'=-e^{2ix} \implies ze^{2ix}=-\int e^{2ix} dx=-e^{2ix}/2i+K$$
$$\implies y'=Ke^{-2ix}-\frac 1 {2i}$$
Integrate to get $y(x)$
$$y=C_1e^{-2ix}+C_2+\frac {ix}2$$